# Fragment Option Menu in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-optionsmenu

I am using a Custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` for SwipeViews in `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` mode.

I want the Fragments inside the adapter to provide their custom Menus. But I observed that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method inside the Fragment is not getting called even when I used `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`
 inside the `onCreate()` callback of the Fragment.

**In short,How can I get custom Options Menu for each Fragment in ViewPager?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your problem seems to lie in `ViewPager`. Either its not instantiated properly or its Visibility is set to `Visibility.GONE`.
Make sure that `ViewPager` is Visible on screen by default or there is no code which changes its visibility.  Get back to me if problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Please write the code in onCreateOptionsMenu & onPrepareOptionsMenu of your activity to inflate the from menu xml. You can then customize the menu in your fragment by using these functions inside your fragment again. I tried it and it worked for me.